# Using Java Mail

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I would like to send an email using my Java Application. 
When I press a button, there should be automatically sent an email , but somehow I didn't find the solution yet.
I found a lot of example codes in the internet, but it doesn't matter if I use Gmail / gmx or outlook, I always receive the message :

"Could not connect to SMTP host: mail.gmx.net, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Based on the domain, so the host is mail.gmx.net or smtp.office365.com etc..
So I think there's somehow a connection problem, but I wasn't able to fix it. 
Do you have some ideas / codes that worked for you ?

Thank you in advance.

Tobias

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at how to post a [MCVE].

Comment: 'Connection timed out/ connect' usually indicates a firewall problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for send Email .This works fine for me

```
package SendMail;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 * @author akash073
 *
 */

public class CrunchifyJavaMailExample {

    //static Properties mailServerProperties;
   // static Session getMailSession;
  //  static MimeMessage generateMailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        generateAndSendEmail();
        System.out.println("\n\n ===> Your Java Program has just sent an Email successfully. Check your email..");
    }

    public static void generateAndSendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String smtpHost="put Your Host";
        String smtpUser="UserName in full @somthing.com";
        String smtpPassword="your password";
        int smtpPort=25;//Port may vary.Check yours smtp port
        // Step1
        System.out.println("\n 1st ===> setup Mail Server Properties..");
        Properties mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
        //mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
//        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true); // added this line
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.user", smtpUser);
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.password", smtpPassword);
        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

        mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        System.out.println("Mail Server Properties have been setup successfully..");

        // Step2
        System.out.println("\n\n 2nd ===> get Mail Session..");
        Session getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
        MimeMessage generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
        generateMailMessage.setFrom (new InternetAddress (smtpUser));
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("akash073@waltonbd.com"));
        generateMailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("akash073@gmail.com"));
        generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings from Crunchify..");
        String emailBody = "2.Test email by Crunchify.com JavaMail API example. " + "<br><br> Regards, <br>Crunchify Admin";
        generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");
        System.out.println("Mail Session has been created successfully..");

        // Step3
        System.out.println("\n\n 3rd ===> Get Session and Send mail");
        Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        // Enter your correct gmail UserID and Password
        // if you have 2FA enabled then provide App Specific Password
        transport.connect(smtpHost,smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    }
}
```

For more info [crunchify](http://crunchify.com/java-mailapi-example-send-an-email-via-gmail-smtp/)

Comment: Nothing here that would solve the actual problem reported by the OP.